# My jquery code is not animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im new to jquery. But it does not seem to work. I am trying to animate and i have literally copied and pasted a code in a notepad and saved it as xxx.html as you would. Where i got it from is the jquery site here - https://api.jqueryui.com/bounce-effect/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>bounce demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <style>
  #toggle {
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     background: #ccc;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Click anywhere to toggle the box.</p>
<div id="toggle"></div>

<script>
    $( document ).click(function() {
    $( "#toggle" ).toggle( "bounce", { times: 3 }, "slow" );
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It works perfectly in the site but when i run it on Google chrome or opera, it just does not work. It does not animate. I'm not sure why. Can anyone help please? Thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did you link the JQuery library in your HTML code? Also posting your code would help anyone attempting to answer, greatly.

Comment: You should provide a minimum required code so people can try to help instead of doing guesswork, have you included jQuery and jQuery UI libs in your html? also always check your console (**F12**)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running the example locally on your computer by opening the file and not by running it via a webserver.

The example uses `//` to load the jQuery files which means that it follows the protocol you used in your browser bar. For example `http://` or `https://`.

However because you opened it locally via `file://` it tries to load the other files also via `file://`. You don't have the other files locally.

Easiest way to fix it is by manually update the jQuery paths and add a protocol so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

An other way to fix it without changing the code is to run the file via a webserver and requesting it via `https://xxxxx.xxx` or `http://xxxxx.xxx`